# How do you control the "path" that a user takes through a Django app?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a Django application where I want to guarantee that a newly registered user has gone through and submitted the forms on a set of 3 pages. I want to control his ability to access any other urls until he has completed these forms. The sequence of pages come after the `User` instance has been created because I am using [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) for Facebook authentication.

I can imaging creating a middleware class where a model is used to record which step he has finished and redirects him to the next required step if he tries to access any other url. There would need to be a whitelist of excepted urls for ajax endpoints if any are needed on the 3 pages. This feels like a bad way to implement this. What are the alternatives?

Comment: I store this information in the users session and as mentioned below check the value in a decorator and redirect as necessary.

Comment: I should put this decorator on every view in my application?

Comment: I only put it on certain pages. Like, the payment page must have been preceded by the registration page and so forth. But, I don't put it on the control panel because the User can't get to that page without having passed through the signup process.

Comment: @hekevintran: if you need to do it on every page, then you might also consider using Middleware (processed after the session has been loaded) to make sure they have traversed the Holy Three Pages. :-) Make sure you don't create an infinite loop by checking to see if they are *on* the appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the "`process_completed`" or alike variable to `True` and do boolean check in a piece of middleware that checks for this variable.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a python decorator to control this.

Comment: -1, provide some detail on how to apply it to the case in question